# Which std::sync::atomic::Ordering to use?

Tags: std, rust, synchronization, atomic

All the methods of [`std::sync::atomic::AtomicBool`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html) take a memory ordering (Relaxed, Release, Acquire, AcqRel, and SeqCst), which I have not used before. Under what circumstances should these values be used? The documentation uses confusing “load” and “store” terms which I don’t really understand. For example:

A producer thread mutates some state held by a [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html), then calls [`AtomicBool`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicBool.html)::`compare_and_swap(false, true, ordering)` (to coalesce invalidations), and if it swapped, posts an “invalidate” message to a concurrent queue (e.g. [`mpsc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/index.html) or a winapi `PostMessage`). A consumer thread resets the `AtomicBool`, reads from the queue, and reads the state held by the Mutex. Can the producer use Relaxed ordering because it is preceded by a mutex, or must it use Release? Can the consumer use `store(false, Relaxed)`, or must it use `compare_and_swap(true, false, Acquire)` to receive the changes from the mutex?

What if the producer and consumer share a [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) instead of a `Mutex`?

Comment: The memory orderings are the same as LLVM's (or C++'s; the rust docs are inconsistent), so you may find [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync), [this](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#memory-model-for-concurrent-operations), and [this](http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html#atomic-orderings) useful.

Comment: FWIW, I use *Sequentially Consistent* (`SeqCst`) because it's the most restrictive (least likely for me to screw it up) and I don't know what all the others mean. ^_^

Comment: [Read here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

Comment: @Shepmaster: in c++, seq_cst usually results in an `MFENCE` instruction on x86, while all of the weaker orderings don't (because x86 does them for free with every load and store).  Jeff Preshing's blog has some great material that will help you understand memory ordering, e.g. http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/.  I wrote an answer recently with a lot of links to that and other sources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384901/atomic-operations-stdatomic-and-ordering-of-writes/32394427#32394427

Comment: Herb Sutter has a great talk about atomics in C++: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-1-of-2. I think essentially all of that applies to Rust. The summary of the talk is that SeqCst is what you want the vast majority of the time.

Comment: "The documentation uses confusing “load” and “store” terms which I don’t really understand." - I would say that understanding these terms is a prerequisite to using atomics at all. So make sure to read the excellent links in the other comments and answers.

Answer (score 38):

I'm not an expert on this, and it's really complicated, so please feel free to critique my post. As pointed out by mdh.heydari, cppreference.com has [much better documentation of orderings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) than Rust (C++ has an almost identical API).

---

## For your question

You'd need to use "release" ordering in your producer and "acquire" ordering in your consumer. This ensures that the data mutation occurs before the `AtomicBool` is set to true.

If your queue is asynchronous, then the consumer will need to keep trying to read from it in a loop, since the producer could get interrupted between setting the `AtomicBool` and putting something in the queue.

If the producer code might run multiple times before client runs, then you can't use `RefCell` because they could mutate the data while the client is reading it. Otherwise it's fine.

There are other better and simpler ways to implement this pattern, but I assume you were just giving it as an example.

---

## What are orderings?

The different orderings have to do with what another thread sees happen when an atomic operation occurs. Compilers and CPUs are normally both allowed to reorder instructions in order to optimize code, and the orderings effect how much they're allowed to reorder instructions.

You could just always use `SeqCst`, which basically guarantees everyone will see that instruction as having occurred wherever you put it relative to other instructions, but in some cases if you specify a less restrictive ordering then LLVM and the CPU can better optimize your code.

You should think of these orderings as applying to a memory location (instead of applying to an instruction).

## Ordering Types

### Relaxed Ordering

There are no constraints besides any modification to the memory location being atomic (so it either happens completely or not at all). This is fine for something like a counter if the values retrieved by/set by individual threads don't matter as long as they're atomic.

### Acquire Ordering

This constraint says that any variable reads that occur in your code after "acquire" is applied can't be reordered to occur before it. So, say in your code you read some shared memory location and get value `X`, which was stored in that memory location at time `T`, and then you apply the "acquire" constraint. Any memory locations that you read from after applying the constraint will have the value they had at time `T` or later.

This is probably what most people would expect to happen intuitively, but because a CPU and optimizer are allowed to reorder instructions as long as they don't change the result, it isn't guaranteed.

In order for "acquire" to be useful, it has to be paired with "release", because otherwise there's no guarantee that the other thread didn't reorder its write instructions that were supposed to occur at time `T` to an earlier time.

Acquire-reading the flag value you're looking for means you won't see a stale value somewhere else that was actually changed by a write before the release-store to the flag.

### Release Ordering

This constraint says that any variable writes that occur in your code before "release" is applied can't be reordered to occur after it. So, say in your code you write to a few shared memory locations and then set some memory location t at time `T`, and then you apply the "release" constraint. Any writes that appear in your code before "release" is applied are guaranteed to have occurred before it.

Again, this is what most people would expect to happen intuitively, but it isn't guaranteed without constraints.

If the other thread trying to read value `X` doesn't use "acquire", then it isn't guaranteed to see the new value with respect to changes in other variable values. So it could get the new value, but it might not see new values for any other shared variables.  Also keep in mind that testing is *hard*.  Some hardware won't in practice show re-ordering with some unsafe code, so problems can go undetected.

[Jeff Preshing wrote a nice explanation of acquire and release semantics](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/), so read that if this isn't clear.

### AcqRel Ordering

This does both `Acquire` and `Release` ordering (ie. both restrictions apply). I'm not sure when this is necessary - it might be helpful in situations with 3 or more threads if some `Release`, some `Acquire`, and some do both, but I'm not really sure.

### SeqCst Ordering

This is most restrictive and, therefore, slowest option. It forces memory accesses to appear to occur in one, identical order to every thread.  This requires an `MFENCE` instruction on x86 on all writes to atomic variables (full memory barrier, including StoreLoad), while the weaker orderings don't.  (SeqCst loads don't require a barrier on x86, as you can see in [this C++ compiler output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22intel%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4CGAXA9gWxBAPgCgiBnDOALks13xRjFJAHMwE4koswWCkAggG4SRbryRoIEBKVIAKAG5YQcAJRIA3kgBOCDDB1hBAOm5o488lUo4EOLDoCeAfUeIdLqQEcYIPWpCSAC%2BYjwsktKypC4Q5Eoq6lq6%2BobGAmZYFlYU1HYOzm46Hi6kCN6x5IEhYRLkjgjy4hEAHhraegZGgkgAvEgtQaFAA%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B1y%20-O3%20-march%3Dnative%20-mtune%3Dnative%22%7D%5D%7D).)

Read-Modify-Write accesses, like atomic increment, or compare-and-swap, are done on x86 with `lock`ed instructions, which are already full memory barriers.  If you care at all about compiling to efficient code on non-x86 targets, it makes sense to avoid SeqCst when you can, even for atomic read-modify-write ops.  [There are cases where it's needed](http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/), though.

For more examples of how atomic semantics turn into ASM, see [this larger set of simple functions on C++ atomic variables](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4CGAXA9gWxBAPgCgB6EgZwzgC5rNd8VwMA2AFgH0MCk0BuJILJIIuAA4goyAO4gMACyQBaHAGYATEgBmWAE5IF4AObkDWJEYQYkzBLoSVjRSjTrY8EJmG68%2BRZkgARgAUAAwAlH4utPQeXj4QfkQw5MZIYGg4DmJoEMguSQBuWCBwSORWwcWl4UQA3kSCgUgAvEjqfkIkvK1IAIwCwuSZyGimaAB0lHoIwX0ANOVUtFk4egCeHHqIuhwVAI4cEJSRRI1IZLH4eyBGGVAcWgiQs6sbW7o7HLmH9lCnXSuEBudzQDyeL2Cb10m22dg4fwQYwQkS6SzQYDgSjBWDAyAAyth7ISZkE0LpdCA7OdLlMibMFkhobDPvC%2FmgAB4IOCnc6Tab2OaLZkfL6I5Goi7dIwQCBBGBGAD8SFkCiwMGsQJB90ezzywXFFXCixlcqkaEKDiQ6usCmQgRamkCCB09gM8hApmCHIAHCxrWAoOtwhNBNAMUYkHAsA4wAByDATc6CFOptPp1PCexiPQYbm8UzyDAYMTkahkU0TO4wCZ6IwkQIKgBekigaAo8iw0g4jaMEwgRhAitKLRYAHY2ABWH1nQF0mZCpkINYw0Xwn4wED2SXCMS6LBwGB5Uw4CF5ZVIACSABEANIq%2BSYHoCmRyRQbrfILIY8izoK9VQBClJA9wPI8rTQdpMSWUlsCCRZUhed1kAwaRzDGVI7iybxxjdXFrTEHNUjzcpSitLAtGfekzCo1wgQMdYxAQGlukCLAFAI0xwGQ8oRnKBB9hgPVkBzAJXW0BBpDsCSXnIC8ADksCYk1ZSQAArFJrGjWME345caKUjAQDwJsUPkZAIGRB87DMmzeDdMBzCgLA0DgcgkzRYI5TadRwiQABqJBgkgto%2BlOABfM5qjKCoMGcpSqhKHkkAaQRxOCAIQBaUIBBAFBAJsfz%2FL81KU2aNoxyA4RRBwCQpH0Sz42sMQYCgKB3U9GC8I1a1KLtJB4rEIIEEslIZBkSkSLQZNeHnQUWAQ5ZqBFOFdkNFFBm6EL%2Bk6JBIsi0huhwVqjLEKQZOPRYEEtMADDQskIAAayUbAlECXJHoDJAAEEACUAFkgsc6w%2Fv%2B9hwmoJAixLMsK1lKswBrOsG2bVt23ITtu17ftB2HOBRwnFg%2BiIaLSNqqQ9kqaLwjqXgWgGOmGbQFoCogR0BGZgqDoCexXI4RygUSmoUqQewMBgXRbsCARIp5pEdiF5LSrFiWpYC3wiFl7xRfl74IEEz9FZKlielEMByBgLJ9G4yDQMPPJdCUM2LatpkDwQKB5hNxtrGdaRyTMp8VtZXZnctr8kXN8pcCsD0wEjD2KnOFXJdm5zXKhZd3lWvWDe3PwtesXm4C4NDvncfByCNlLk6sVWekCxI0VNXhoPDeOgnYxQtDQSQaLG3g4DKVV3yXFd1gIuwMTgJMDpJpK3bgEAtHWavSsCIrdrQTfNfn0pF%2BXzZ2S5OA175CYngwCB5G%2BIfgjYYUs9XHPj%2B5Hdul9FhIccNqemcp6QL2C0CADkixnSjQqEgT%2BUMxjpHMF3aS%2Ft1i71JmsJeK9c4Ig9mfQQkxL7X1vqfB%2BY9s4h0wX8d%2BUC%2FTfyMr%2FSC%2F9Pp7hdCAsBI00AD2gY%2BUwjlrR2n0Eg3eAQaqBHALMamNc0Qp1upBfybRpZogYVA1yZRggIA5NfCMoxoLKL8nBXEQYdauVwYIXEeQ%2BQBTkbtKRGtC4GAcBgHBNhKLBWNqmaxTdgLLxEDYcgTVeAVwgCpOUY1xgiDWIUGw5s8xGIoj0QIugMTX3OJFQQ1jpa72EKASAsBECoDBEYPQb4cDEACDgTkhQwSOOsZBHgEBlSQUhokFi1jojLU5MFMBEUzilPKWCXOm5BTiNKgEDA21Jjp1PsHL4H587AQADIuTgAsox70KRUn0OZN0oE8wQAwKYfq9hKC13FqnUZSBakTAmZncea41oe05G%2FJAioZppjOY0y5izrmkLFPck%2BlCf7tQmaE9Q0EjJZFDEgRSRdfn5meOqIwihyzNLrqnVpZSOQdKCF0%2Fw2t0UVIeI5MAHBOxrMCFIRx7C4JnLaOMz5Uz1z6wGRtPkGpzBX16BAD5Gd6V3LbH8qxKLbpnJ4Oy5UbyDBNLniQAAVEgRosr8Byj6KoJkaBHpWhJZSMlFl3baD0DxYu0ktAwEgEZXE1B5VMjPPaF0MwSBoC0HmfQSJr4DUWYsEed1zA21Fl2SJPE8BDykEQaVJAgAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g520%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%20-O3%22%7D%5D%7D).  I know this is a Rust question, but it's supposed to have basically the same API as C++.  godbolt can target x86, ARM, ARM64, and PowerPC.  Interestingly, ARM64 has load-acquire (`ldar`) and store-release (`stlr`) instructions, so it doesn't always have to use separate barrier instructions.

---

By the way, x86 CPUs are always "strongly ordered" by default, which means they always act as if at least `AcqRel` mode was set. So for x86 "ordering" only affects how LLVM's optimizer behaves. ARM, on the other hand, is weakly ordered.  `Relaxed` is set by default, to allow the compiler full freedom to reorder things, and to not require extra barrier instructions on weakly-ordered CPUs.

Comment: I found http://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/ and Preshing's other articles excellent for wrapping my head around this stuff.  SeqCst requires the CPU to prevent even StoreLoad re-ordering, which requires an MFENCE instruction on x86.  This is expensive.  It's not that it "locks down the bus", it's just that it can't use prefetched data that was read before the last store became globally visible.  On x86, though, all read-modify-write ops (like atomic increment, or compare-and-swap) are also full memory barriers, so seqcst comes for free with them.)

Comment: I did introduce one error, which I just fixed:  seq_cst loads of atomic variables don't require an MFENCE, only stores.  I linked to some c++ compiler output on godbolt, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32384901/atomic-operations-stdatomic-and-ordering-of-writes/32394427#32394427.  If there's something similar for Rust, that would be ideal, but I don't know Rust at all myself.  I just jumped in since the API is the same as C++ atomics.

Comment: @PeterCordes Godbolt has a [Rust version](https://rust.godbolt.org/) and the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) likewise allows for ASM output. I'd recommend adding the Rust-specific output if possible.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Thanks for the links.  I have literally never used Rust, so I'll leave that for someone else (perhaps Michael).  I agree that Rust code would be better for this answer.

Comment: I found an article that explains the ordering methods in more detail with examples: https://cfsamsonbooks.gitbook.io/explaining-atomics-in-rust/